# How Google OAuth 2.0 token count?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I want to use Goole Login for Organization (internal use)

But I have login saperately IPs (Computer & Mobile phone) with 2 accounts
But not have any limit counter change, it show only "0" used

I want to know. 
"How count Google oauth limit"

[image]
[image]

Comment: "How Google count oauth limit"   <- what limit??

Comment: yes that google oauth was limit 10000 use per day 

but I have viewed statistic that no have my usage

Comment: Wow never seen that before where is that screen?

Comment: https://console.developers.google.com

Comment: That screen must be very new its the first i have seen it and i was in there last week.  I dont think its going to be a live update when did you log those users in i would wait a few days.  IN the mean time i will contact google see if i can find out how often its updated

Comment: thank you i concern about limit because i used about 30000+ in only 1 day

Comment: Apply for the limit to be raised once you have reached 80% of the limit is standard practice.

Comment: that mean if user reached ~8,000 will raised ?

Comment: yeah something like that.

Comment: Ok. I should request my quota ASAP. Thank you